# iframe width 100% not really span page

Tags: html, iframe, width, margin

I've given my `<iframe>` tag a style of `style="width:100%"`, and it almost spans the page, except that it leaves a small margin on the left and right side. (I've tried on both Firefox and Chrome, and the result is the same.) This doesn't look like such a big deal, but it's better if the `iframe` leaves no left and right margin. Is there a way to make it so?

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code - ideally a jsFiddle

Comment: It's interesting... in jsFiddle the margin does *not* appear. http://jsfiddle.net/7MXz5/ But on my browser it does appear.

Comment: In your CSS add `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` - should fix it

Comment: Looks like just `margin: 0` does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS works for me in Firefox:

```
body { margin:0px; }
iframe { width:100%; height:100%; border:none }
```

Comment: Looks like just `body { margin:0px; }` does the trick! (don't need `border:none`)

Answer (score 0):

`style="width:100%;margin:0 -10px 0 -10px;"`

or whatever amount you think it would need to bring it to the edges. The negative numbers are giving it a negative margin so it should stretch to the outside edges, if not make it -20px.